# undefined error with MySql insert trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

I'm trying to write a MySQL insert trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger1` BEFORE INSERT ON  `COMPANY` 
FOR EACH ROW

IF NEW.DOKUMENTTYP LIKE 'test'
AND NEW.STATUS LIKE 'neu'
THEN 
INSERT INTO my_tools.testimport( processname, version, step, insstring, initiator ) 
VALUES ( 'COMPANY_ER', 0, 1, CONCAT( 'DWDOCID=', NEW.DWDOCID ) ,  'robot' );
END IF;
```

But there's an error in my SQL syntax. I cannot find the solution. Could anybody please help me?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: 1.) "syntax error: missing semicolon" after the last closing parenthesis 
2.) "end is not valid input at this position" at "END IF;"

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
 IF (NEW.DOKUMENTTYP LIKE 'test' AND NEW.STATUS LIKE 'neu') ...

Comment: Same errors again: "missing semicolon" after the last closing parenthesis and "end is not valid input at this position" at "END IF;" ...

Comment: As @Devart said you need to add "BEGIN"  and "END" to your code

Answer (score 0):

Triggers body contains more then one statement, it means that BEGIN..END keywords must be used. And add DELIMITERs, if needed:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `trigger1`
BEFORE INSERT
ON `Company`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.DOKUMENTTYP LIKE 'test' AND NEW.Status LIKE 'neu' THEN
    INSERT INTO my_tools.testimport (processname, VERSION, step, insstring, initiator)
      VALUES ('COMPANY_ER', 0, 1, CONCAT('DWDOCID=', NEW.DWDOCID), 'robot');
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```